# Are music reality show questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are music reality show questions on-topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question. Their status on Movies & TV seems [a bit vague](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/why-limit-the-scope-of-television), and it's unclear if they're a good fit there.

Personally, I think that questions regarding *music* or *musicians* should be on topic here even if the music or musician in question perform as part of a reality TV show, but questions about the *show* (its production, hosts and so on) shouldn't be.

Comment: [Non-music related reality show question are well accepted over Movies and TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/do-the-american-idol-judges-judge-every-contestant)

Comment: What would be the distinction between, say, a question about a record label executive and a question about a producer on *The Voice*?  As long as it's within the context of their work involving music, why should the latter be off-topic?

Comment: I agree - as long as the question is to do with music or musicians it should be OK. If the question would work outside of the context of the reality music show, clearly that's ok, but that's probably too restrictive as a test  to apply.

Answer (score 5):

I would say yes. If the question is a Q&A format, why not?

I, personally don't watch these kind of shows, but there are Music Fans that do.

Answer (score 1):

I think - as always - "it depends"

I think

> Who do you think will win this year's X Factor?

is as far off-topic as it can get.

Same with

> Don't you think *so&so* was out of tune on Sunday?

However, Leona Lewis/JLS et al have far outgrown their reality show beginnings & would be a valid topic of conversation (whether I like them or not;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to declare this questions as off-topic.

The music reality show part could be an important part of the carrer of a musician, and there is no reason to forbid people asking about it. But as any other question, it has to respect standard SE rules.

Answer (score -4):

I think NO. Music reality shows are TV shows, and so are not appropriate or relevant to a Q&A site about music.

Comment: Music doesn't stop being music if it's presented in a particular medium.  Shows like *American Idol* involve a lot of music, and music-related questions can be asked about them.  So they are *clearly* relevant, saying otherwise just doesn't make sense.  I'm sure there's an argument to be made against them, but that isn't one.  No more than "Music reality shows have music, and so are not appropriate or relevant to a Q&A site about TV shows" is a good argument.